# ggplot2: remove one of the legend entries

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some data that I am graphing by an index. One of the values only has NAs. So it doesn't show up on the graph, but the entry still exists in the legend. How can I remove it from the legend?

```
df <- structure(list(yrmonth = structure(c(1483228800, 1483228800, 
      1483228800, 1485907200, 1485907200, 1485907200, 1488326400, 1488326400, 
      1488326400, 1491004800, 1491004800, 1491004800), class = c("POSIXct", 
      "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), index = structure(c(1L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 
      3L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 5L), .Label = c("N-S", "N-S", "E-W", 
      "E-W", "OS"), class = "factor"), value = c(129, 141, NA, 150.5, 
      209, NA, 247.5, 243, NA, 223, 226.5, NA)), .Names = c("yrmonth", 
      "index", "value"), row.names = 31:42, class = "data.frame")

ggplot(df, aes(x=yrmonth,y=value,colour=index)) + 
  geom_line()
```

Comment: Why don't you just remove any `NA`s before plotting? `df[!is.na(df$value),]`

Comment: something's wrong with this example, you can't have two factor levels with the same label

Comment: `ggplot(na.omit(df), aes(x=yrmonth,y=value,colour=index)) + geom_line()`

Comment: @ThomasK works perfect! Thanks.

Comment: Worth pointing out that `na.omit` will omit any row where any value is `NA`. So if you have unused columns that have `NA` those rows will be excluded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example code is somehow messed up, but we can fix it with:

```
df$index <- as.factor(as.character(df$index))
```

Then, you would have multiple options, but for this case an easy one is to use `na.omit`.

```
ggplot(na.omit(df), aes(x = yrmonth, y = value, colour = index)) + 
  geom_line()
```

Be aware however, that this removes all cases with missing values. In your case this is fine, but in other cases it could be useful to remove only cases where your value of interest is missing, which you could do with `df[!is.na(df$value),]`, as Mike. H proposed.